# Is this a blackmail or am I imagining things?

Tags: human-resources, bullying

So I was asking a Growth Manager some question about vacation days, because we didn't get the information before, and I asked him specifically, because he asked us about the vacation days we took, and I was told cc him when I asked for vacation days, and my supervisor who is Indian and who doesn't have a very good English. His English is worse than mine. Told me something along the line of:

> If you keep sending emails to the wrong person, it will affect your personal performance.

Now, I have no idea what he meant by this, but he insulted me one time, and someone left because of him, and two other people said bad things in his back and under his own admission he admitted that he doesn't get along with people and also bragged to us that he lied and manipulated the management team, so I am wondering if I am imagining things, or he did indeed blackmail me here. I am thinking about leaving the company, because I just can't stand the guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you keep sending emails to the wrong person, it will affect your personal performance.

This is what you say:

"Regarding my vacation days, I was just following his specific instructions. My apologies for not letting you know the context of why I was carbon copying him."

In other words, you assume the best possible interpretation of his last communication, you apologize for something else as a way to let him save face, and then if he really wants to coerce you, or push this issue further, he will reply to your message by clarifying what he meant.

But as a rule of thumb, you should always assume that your boss/co-workers are having the best of intentions when they're communicating with you.

And yes, if you dislike your manager that much, you should probably try to transfer to a different team or to a different company.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome new user.  Honestly that is not "blackmail".  I would describe it as "rude" and "unprofessional".

You need to be "even more professional", set aside the rudeness, and carry on professionally.

How to answer?  Just reply "Dear Steve, sorry about that. Actually Frank told me to cc him regarding vacation days. Sorry if there was any confusion."

No "blackmail", just rudeness

Regarding your general comments that you want to leave, etc., I suggest you just leave.  There are a zillion questions on here "My company/boss/project sucks because _ _ _, should I leave?" The answer is always "Yes, leave."

Comment: If you get "mad" you are facing a problem.  Please remember it is just work.  Work, leave at 5.00.00 precisely, take your money, and go home and enjoy your good life with good food!   Please remember that ***every single job has something that sucks***.  If someone at your work is a moron, just be polite, carry on with your business - and again go home to life!  They won't remember your name 30 seconds after you leave the company for your next job, and you won't remember their name.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

"Personal performance" meaning how he rates your performance or just how well you're able to perform? If taken literally, I suppose repeatedly emailing the wrong person could negatively effect your ability to do your job. If he means how he rates your performance, you might say it's a threat but certainly not blackmail.

Blackmail means coercing certain behavior by threatening to reveal information the victim would rather keep secret. That doesn't seem to be the case here and as your manager, it's more or less up to him to decide on what factors to rate your performance, however strange they may seem. Either way, I would ask him to clarify in your next 1:1 meeting as this is a very confusing statement.